# Multiple NavigationView in a screen

Tags: swiftui, navigation, navigationview, swiftui-navigationlink

I've 2 **NavigationView** in a screen.
When I tap a **Go To ChildView** item on list, I want to navigate in **Parent Navigation**.
When I tap a one of other items on list, I want to navigate in **Container Navigation**

How can I push a view to selected NavigationView ? I want to decide from which navigation to push the view.

[image]

Parent View

```
struct Parent: View {
    var body: some View {
    
    NavigationView { // Parent Navigation
        VStack {
            SearchBarView()
            ContainerView() // Container
        }
        .navigationTitle("Parent Navigation")
    }
}}
```

Container View

```
struct ContainerView: View {
    var body: some View {
    NavigationView { // Container Navigation
        List(0..<20) { i in
            
            if i == 0 {
                Text("Go To Child View")
            } else {
                NavigationLink(
                    destination: ChildView(),
                    label: {
                        Text("Text \(i)")
                    })
            }
            
        }
        .navigationTitle("Container Navigation")
        .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.large)
    }
}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to place navigation link *outside* of internal navigation view, ex. in background, like shown below, and activate it programmatically.

```
struct ContainerView: View {
    @State private var isActive = false
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView { // Container Navigation
            List(0..<20) { i in

                if i == 0 {
                    Button("Go To Child View") {
                        isActive = true           // << here !!
                    }
                } else {
                    NavigationLink(
                        destination: ChildView(),
                        label: {
                            Text("Text \(i)")
                        })
                }

            }
            .navigationTitle("Container Navigation")
            .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.large)
        }
        .background(
            NavigationLink(                 // << here !!
                destination: ChildView(),
                isActive: $isActive,
                label: { EmptyView() })
        )
    }
}
```